# Prime number program does not work

Tags: java, primes

I am trying to make a simple program in Java that would output all the prime numbers (skipping number 2) up to the number `n`. It doesn't work and I am out of ideas. If someone could take a look at my code and tell me what the problem is I would greatly appreciate it.

```
public class PrimeNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 50;
        int notAPrime = 0;

        System.out.println("All prime numbers before number " +n+ " are : ");
        for(int i = n; i > 2; i--){
            for(int j = 2; j < i; j++){
                if(i % j == 0){
                  notAPrime++;
                }
            }
            if(notAPrime == 0){
                System.out.println(i);
                notAPrime = 0;  
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: Typographical error: just move `notAPrime=0;` _after_ the if, not in it. Otherwise, you keep incrementing it without setting it to 0 for each number.

Comment: There is no output in this specific situation. If I put the notAPrime=0 outside of if loop, it does not work either. It outputs 3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9.....

Comment: This is a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  With that you can step through the code, line by line, as it executes and observe the runtime values and behavior.  This will help you identify where the problem is happening.

Comment: Iam using NotePad, not JDK.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use Notpad to develop code... Use an IDE for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing a "break" in your for loop.

```
public class primeNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=50;
        int notAPrime=0;

        System.out.println("All prime numbers before number " +n+ " are : ");
        for(int i=n; i>2; i--){
           for(int j=2; j<i; j++){
               if(i%j==0){
                  notAPrime++;
                  break; //your program is missing this statement
               }
            } 
            if(notAPrime==0){
               System.out.print(i + " ");                   
            }   
            notAPrime=0;     //In your program it is inside the if statement which makes it incorrect.
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
All prime numbers before number 50 are : 
47 43 41 37 31 29 23 19 17 13 11 7 5 3

You can make your program more efficient by making the following changes:

```
public class primeNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=50;
        int notAPrime=0;

        System.out.println("All prime numbers before number " +n+ " are : ");
        for(int i=n; i>2; i--){
           if(i%2==0){
               continue;
           }
           for(int j=3; j<i; j+=2){  
               if(i%j==0){
                  notAPrime++;
                  break;
               }
            } 
            if(notAPrime==0){
               System.out.print(i + " ");                   
            }   
            notAPrime=0;     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? This program gives right results.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `notAPrime` inside `for(int i = n; i > 2; i--)` to make it local for each i - candidate to be prime.
Now you increase `notAPrime` and never reset it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class primeNum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 50;
    boolean prime;

    System.out.println("All prime numbers before number " +n+ " are : ");
    for(int i = n; i > 2; i--){
        prime = true;
        for(int j = 2; j < i; j++){
            if(i % j == 0){
              prime = false;
            }
        }
        if(prime){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

}

note, that i changed your "notAPrime" variable from int into boolean and into a name that tells you what it means. if you only increment the "notAPrime" integer, you will never get any desired outcome.
By the way, this wa a *hotfix* and you got a corrected first form of your code. Have in mind, that 2 is a prime number aswell and your code ignores this.
Just work a little mor on it ;)